# JSON Parsing in Titanium Appcelerator Mobile SDK

Tags: iphone, json, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I want to parse following JSON using Titanium Appcelerator Mobile SDK

```
[{"City":null,"Distance":469,"Email":null,"Latitude":0,"Longitude":0,"Name":"Cretin-Derham Hall","PhoneNo":null,"SchoolId":75,"State":null,"Zip":null},{"City":null,"Distance":213,"Email":null,"Latitude":0,"Longitude":0,"Name":"East Ridge","PhoneNo":null,"SchoolId":76,"State":null,"Zip":null},{"City":null,"Distance":26,"Email":null,"Latitude":0,"Longitude":0,"Name":"Hastings","PhoneNo":null,"SchoolId":78,"State":null,"Zip":null},{"City":null,"Distance":116,"Email":null,"Latitude":0,"Longitude":0,"Name":"Stillwater","PhoneNo":null,"SchoolId":81,"State":null,"Zip":null},{"City":null,"Distance":0,"Email":null,"Latitude":0,"Longitude":0,"Name":"White Bear Lake","PhoneNo":null,"SchoolId":82,"State":null,"Zip":null}]
```

I want to parse this and put all "Name" values in TableView/ListView. 
Can anyone help me ?

Here's my current code that I have:

```
   var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function()
{
    Ti.API.info('in utf-8 onload for GET');

    var schools = eval('(' + this.responseText +')');
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the responseText contains the JSON and there is a window available in the `window` variable

```
var tv = Ti.UI.createTableView();
window.add(tv);

xhr.onload = function()
{
    var data = [];
    Ti.API.info('in utf-8 onload for GET');
    var schools = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (s in schools)
    {
        data.push(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({title: schools[s].Name});
    }

    tv.data = data;

};
```